# AI Platform Built-in Image Classification Algorithm doesn't export a model at end of training

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, gcp-ai-platform-training

I've been training using the new [AI Platform Built-in Image Classification Algorithm](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/algorithms/image-classification-start). Often times, despite the training job completing successfully, a saved model is not output to the gs job directory. There are no errors in the logs. The only indication in the logs that something is wrong is the absence of the following lines:

> Performing best model export
>
> SavedModel written to: *jobDirSubDir*/saved_model.pb
>
> Export best SavedModel from *jobDirSubDir* to *jobDirSubDir*/model

The job simply completes after the final evaluation is finished.

Any hints for how to troubleshoot this built-in algorithm would be greatly appreciated. Or, if it's open source please point me at the correct repo.

Thanks

Comment: I am experiencing the exact same issue.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you resolve the issue?

Comment: @rohitsingh Unfortunately I couldn't figure out any way to troubleshoot what is occurring inside of the "built-in algorithm". Since it seems opaque and unreliable, I decided not to use it anymore. In the end I manually implemented a training application in TF 2.0 to run instead.

Comment: Yeah I know it's so frustrating to see that google cloud ai platform not providing details information and even though I checked in stackdriver logs,

Comment: Same issue for me. Any help appreciated!

Comment: I would suggest building the custom model using TF. Well, I moved to azure custom vision and it's easy to use https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/